# How do we know the element is visualized in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8 I am displaying list of items(this list may contain any number of items may be 40 or 50...). When the user pull down I am refreshing the previous list.. so user can see all the items in the list by pulling down. Now my concern is I want to mark these items as read or unread but how do we know these items are visualized by the user and my list box item displays only the text they are not clickable. At present i am using **Emulator WVGA 512MB** in which i can see 5 items at once.

Answer (score 0):

If the items are a fixed size then you could determine if they're on screen by looking at the scrolloffset of the scrollviewer inside the ListBox template. (Get it via the VisualTreeHelper.)

The defacto convention is that if it is not necessary to navigate to a separate page, or interact with it in some other way, to mark an item as read, they are marked as read once displayed.
This works fine for older items but if you're loading new items above the top of the currently displayed items this can be harder. If you're managing the data virtualization yourself you could do this based on when items are realized. If you use the `LongListSelector` it raises an `ItemRealized` event you could use to detect this instead.